# c++ two locks better than one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have a resource (vector, list, whatever) that I am trying to give access to multiple writers/readers.

I'm not sure how to go about this to achieve best performance, ie, minimal amount of locking for a reader if the data structure is locked. Would it be better to use two locks, one called readmutex and the other called writemutex?

So for example:

```
struct Foo {
    mutex writemutex_;
    mutex readmutex_;
    vector<string> data_;
    void write(string data)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> locker(writemutex_);
        data_.emplace_back(move(data));
    }
    string get(int index) const {
        // I don't need to lock for read, but what if the data is being written?
        // and so should I lock lockmutex_? If so, then readmutex_ is unnecessary?
        // is there some cleaver way that I can avoid readers from being blocked?
        return data_[index];
    }

};
```

what other synchronization techniques can I use here?

Comment: This is normally solved by using a "read/write lock" or "shared lock;" that can be locked for reading (multiple threads can do that, if it's not locked for writing) or writing (only 1 can do that, and only if it's not locked at all). C++14 will introduce `std::shared_lock` for this. Until then, you could use a threading library which has such functionality (Boost has it, for example).

Comment: How about conditional locking? Lock on write. And lock on read only when write happens in the meantime.

Comment: @freakish: You wouldn't know. The write may happen at any time _after_ it's checked that a write is happening, but before the actual read commences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shared_mutex` which is available in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) and will be part of [C++14](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/compliance.html#thread.compliance.cxx14).

```
struct Foo 
{
    using mutex = boost::shared_mutex;
    using write_lock = boost::unique_lock<mutex>;
    using read_lock = boost::shared_lock<mutex>;

    mutable mutex mutex_;
    vector<string> data_;

    void write(string data)
    {
        write_lock lock{ mutex_ };
        data_.emplace_back(move(data));
    }

    string get(int index) const 
    {
        read_lock lock{ mutex_ };
        return data_[index];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [Readers–writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). But you should take into account that in some scenaries rw lock may be more slowly than exclusive lock

There are a lot of implementations, e.g. in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex). WinAPI also has [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (since Vista or Server 2008)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your primary question: No, using two locks isn't better. It's in fact incorrect. You need the write lock to prevent races, and while holding the write lock there's no need for any additional read lock.

The other answers do have the correct alternative (shared_mutex, which implements a reader-write lock), but don't explain why it's needed.